# Java Regex How to Find if String Contains Characters but order is not a matter

Tags: java, regex

I have String like this **"abcdefgh"**

I want to check the string contains the following characters **[fcb]**

Condition is : The string **must contain** all characters in **any order**.

How to write a regex for this one.

I tried following regexes :

**.*[fcb].***  --->  In this case it not check all characters. If any one character matchs it will return true

Comment: Did you try `[fcb]+`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun  that would match `"fff"`.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use regex. Just use `String.contains` to test for each of the characters in turn:

```
in.contains("f") && in.contains("c") && in.contains("b")
```

Comment: Is it more efficient than regex check? Just asking as I don't know.

Comment: Lots more efficient than a single regex.  More efficient than multiple regexes.

Answer (score 3):

You could get the char arry and sort it. Afterwards you could check if it contains `.*b.*c.*f.*`.

```
public static boolean contains(String input) {
    char[] inputChars = input.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(inputChars);
    String bufferInput = String.valueOf(inputChars);
    // Since it is sorted this will check if it simply contains `b,c and f`.
    return bufferInput.matches(".*b.*c.*f.*");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(contains("abcdefgh"));
    System.out.println(contains("abdefgh"));
}
```

output:

```
true 
false
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun after the sort the order doesn´t matter anymore, it simply checks if all values are present. (Or i do have a logical error)

Answer (score 3):

this will check if all the letters are present in the string.

```
public class Example {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    String stringA = "abcdefgh";

    String opPattern = "(?=[^ ]*f)(?=[^ ]*c)(?=[^ ]*b)[^ ]+";
    Pattern opPatternRegex = Pattern.compile(opPattern);

    Matcher matcher = opPatternRegex.matcher(stringA);

    System.out.println(matcher.find());

}
}
```

Comment: This works fine. But I can't understand your pattern logic. Could you explain or post a link. So it will helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use `positive lookahead` for this

```
(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient but easy to understand:

```
if (s.matches(".*b.*") && s.matches(".*c.*") && s.matches(".*f.*"))
```