# ES5 Regex test find a set of characters in any order

Tags: javascript, regex, set, character

Say I want to find a word in the dictionary that contain a given set of letters in any order.  For my example, my regex character set contains [jock]. I have been trying to create a function that creates a regex test like this:

```
/*
** Function: Take an array of 2 strings. Return TRUE if all letters
**           of 2nd string are within 1st string, letters can be any order,
**            case-sensitivity does not matter.
**
** @param    {array} where arr[0] word to check, arr[1] string of characters
** @returns  {array} 
*/
function matchAllLetters(arr) {
  'use strict';

  // flags: i - case insensitive, g - global match

  var pattern = new RegExp("[" + arr[0] + "+]", "ig"); 

  return ( pattern.test( arr[1] ) );
}
matchAllLetters(['jackal','jock']); //true, s/b false
```

I am aware there are ways other than using RegExp to solve this, but I would like to solve this problem with RegExp so that I can compare RegExp against another approach with JSPerf.

Comment: Syntax Error: `matchAllLetters(['jackal','jock';]);`

Comment: what is the actual problem?

Comment: I guess you meant `new RegExp("^[" + arr[0] + "]+$", "i")`

Comment: @Nina. The problem is test returns true, but the letter 'o' within arr[1] should  make the function return false.

Comment: @Ryan.  Your solution worked for me but since you answered in a comment, I can only +1 it.  Can you explain to me why  "^[" and "]$", specifically adding carat and dollar-sign symbols were required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nahuel's answer steered me in the right direction. In my earlier attempt I tried to pass a string of characters 'jock' as a character pattern for regex to use in order to match a string.  The set of letters 'j','o','c','k' could be in found in any order of the string, just as long as they were found within the string. As Nahuel pointed out I couldn't just take the'jock' string and surround it by a character class [], because regex returns TRUE if even only 1 of the characters in the set matches and the rest don't.  This [Java Regex discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277961/java-regex-how-to-find-if-string-contains-characters-but-order-is-not-a-matter) on stack overflow helped me rewrite my function to build a 'positive lookahead' regex test.

```
function matchAllLetters(arr) {

  var len= arr[1].length;
  var lookahead = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    lookahead += "(?=.*" + arr[1].charAt(i) + ")";
  }

  var pattern = new RegExp(lookahead, "i"); 
  return ( pattern.test( arr[0] ) );
}
```

The function works as expected.  But as mentioned, the entire purpose was to see 
if Regex was faster than other methods at pattern matching in this manner. For those interested you can find my JSPerf tests [here](https://jsperf.com/mutation-eggs)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the regex returns true because it matches one character of set [can be checked on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2ST2dB/1/) to match the whole string anchors and quantifier must be added as suggested by @Ryan.

```
^[jackal]+$
```

note the `a` is redundant because it appears twice in character set.

Comment: A nice online tool.  Actually 'jackal' is the word to check and 'jock' is the inclusive set of characters to be used in the regex test to see if the word validates True.

Comment: @Eggs, in this case you should write `new RegExp("^["+arr[1]+"]+$")` and `pattern.test(arr[0])`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression with

- `^` start position
- `[]` a character class, which may be empty
- `*` a greedy quantifier for zero until unlimited time (needed for empty character class)
- `$` end position of the string

```js
'use strict';

function matchAllLetters(arr) {
    var pattern = new RegExp("^[" + arr[0] + "]*$", "ig"); 
    return pattern.test(arr[1]);
}

console.log(matchAllLetters(['jackal', 'jock']));
console.log(matchAllLetters(['', '']));
console.log(matchAllLetters(['jackal', 'jack']));
```